# Magento version2 reindex option is not in admin side

Tags: magento

There is no option to reindex in magento Version2 admin side.
Tried to command prompt reindex is working. But my client dont know about cmd prompt. there is any other option to reindex data. Please help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
try {
$indx = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("php bin/magento indexer:reindex"));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($indx);
} catch(Exception $e)
{
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```

Paste this code in a file with name say reindex.php in magento2 root directory. Then use the `{magento-url}/reindex.php` to reindex.

Comment: This does not work. The reindex command is incorrect. the correct syntax is  `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: still +1 for the approach